# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MONTH(date)' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

i dont see what's my problem here, im just trying to get the month and the year from a date column in my DB, i was already using this query and it was working and now its not i really dont understand. ( new to laravel)

heres my controller:

```
public function showMonth($month, $year)
    {
        $workers = WorkerSalarie::all();

        $worker = WorkerSalarie::select('*')
        ->where('MONTH(date)','=',$month)
        ->where('YEAR(date)','=',$year)
        ->get();

        return view('backoffice.dashboard.show', compact('month', 'year', 'workerss'));

    }
```

and this is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MONTH(date)' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select * from `worker_salaries` where `MONTH(date)` = 3 and 
`YEAR(date)` = 2021)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28226522/7491884).

Since Laravel prepares the querys before excuting them, you can use the `whereMonth` and `whereYear` methods to tell Laravel to not escape your clauses:

Change this:

```
->where('MONTH(date)','=',$month)
->where('YEAR(date)','=',$year)
```

For this:

```
->whereMonth('date', '=', $month])
->whereYear('date', '=', $year)
```

Check the docs for this methods [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses).

Other (less clean) option would be to use the [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-methods) method.

Comment: thank you thats a good answer but its more simple to use whereMonth() and whereYear()

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my answer.